# How to map special character field in Mule 3 dataweave?

Tags: special-characters, encode, dataweave, mulesoft, mel

I have an XML payload which consists of many fields out of which there is one field which has special character. **Antigüedad** is the field name and I am transforming this XML payload to JSON as `Antigüedad: payload.@Antigüedad` I am getting an error as invalid input ü expected is *

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should work if you wrap the selector in quotes such as

```
"Antigüedad": payload.@"Antigüedad"
```

Comment: When I am trying to transform JSON to XML in a similar way as above with quotes, the field is not appearing? Do you know the reason ?    I have this field under a node             
 Acceptor @("Antigüedad": payload.Acceptor."Antigüedad") this is what I have in the dataweave, but, the field is not generated.